# how to properly use recursive function call to return the property of a nested object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular app, I'm using AngularTree directive (http://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control) to render a tree view of the following data structure:

```
$scope.subjectAreas = [
        {
            name:   "Area-1",
            link:   "dashboards.dashboard_1",
            entities: [
                {
                    name: "entity 1"
                },
                {
                    name: "entity 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name:   "Area-2",
            link:   "dashboards.dashboard_1",
            entities: [
                {
                    name: "entity 3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name:   "Area-3",
            link:   "dashboards.dashboard_1",
            entities: [
                {
                    name: "entity 4"
                },
                {
                    name: "entity 5"
                },
                {
                    name: "entity 6"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

This treeView directive provides the "createSubTree" function, which I'm using as follows:

```
function createSubTree(level, width, prefix) {
        if (level > 0) {
            var res = [];
            for (var i=1; i <= width; i++)
                res.push({ "label" : getName(i), "id" : "id"+prefix + i, "i": i,
                    "children": createSubTree(level-1, setNumberOfChildren(getName(i),i), prefix + i +".")});
            return res;
        }
        else
            return [];
    }
```

Here are my supporting functions:

```
function countNumberOfEntities(index){

        return $scope.subjectAreas[index].entities.length;
    }

    function getSubjectAreasLength(){
        return $scope.subjectAreas.length;
    }

    function setNumberOfChildren(subjectArea, index){
        var numberOfChildEntities = countNumberOfEntities(index-1);
        return numberOfChildEntities;
    }

    function getName(index){
        if($scope.subjectAreas[index-1]){
            var subjectAreaName = $scope.subjectAreas[index-1].name;
            var n = subjectAreaName;
            return subjectAreaName;
        }
    }
```

The tree view renders fine, but all children (names of entities, which belong to a given SubjectArea) end up having the same names as their parent (SubjectArea).

The current rendering looks like this:

```
Area-1
   Area-1
   Area-2
Area-2
   Area-1
Area-3
   Area-1
   Area-2
   Area-3
```

What this needs to look like is:

```
Area-1
   Entity-1
   Entity-2
Area-2
   Entity-3
Area-3
   Entity-4
   Entity-5
   Entity-6
```

How can I modify this "createSubTree" function to return the name of each entity, when it is being called recursively here:  `"children": createSubTree(level-1, setNumberOfChildren(getName(i),i), prefix + i +".")});`

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: @Will, here my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/Lvwxx629/9/  I was unable to add the png images of the folder used by the tree view directive. So, you will just need to click to the left of each top-level node to have the tree expended. The rest works, and illustrates the issue.

Comment: Just added the tree view images: https://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/Lvwxx629/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
function createSubTree(ary) {
    var res = [];
    if (ary) {
        res = ary.map(function(v, k) {
            var id = k + 1;
            return {
                i: id,
                id: 'id' + id,
                label: v.name,
                children: createSubTree(v.entities)
            }
        });

    }
    return res;
}



$scope.treedata = createSubTree($scope.subjectAreas);
```

Try to avoid sending indexes and such in recursive approach.  There are times that you can't help but send indexes, but in this case, you're fine with sending the main array and call the same run recursively with each element's child array.

Comment: Thank you for helping me sole this!  If I was to add another array "offerings", as per updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/Lvwxx629/17/   - how should I change the syntax in order to produce a subfolder for both - entities and offerings, and have entities become children of each "entities" subfolder, and offerings become children of each "offerings" subfolder?   If you'd prefer a separate question for this, I'll open one up

Comment: One question is fine, but can you update the question and in the UPDATE section, show your desired output, similar to what you've done with the original question.  It's easier if we see the actual desired outcome.

Comment: Just posted as a new question, so you can have another full credit:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070428/how-to-properly-use-recursive-function-to-go-through-multiple-nested-objects